# Drupal search was performed using the query 500 shtml

Tags: drupal

Can anyone help why i'm receiving this message:

*"The page you requested does not exist. For your convenience, a search was performed using the query 500 shtml."*

This prevent me from posting some content on my live site, but in my development site, it's just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a 404 search module enable, that performs a search if you get a 404.

A reason why you are getting 404 could be that you have installed or edited a module and need to clear the menu cache.

Comment: This also occurs for me when I have 404 search module enabled and I run cron. If the page times out before cron circles back successfully, 404 search module intercepts the sequence and performs a search with that 500 shtml query.